# GNU package mutually dependent

Tags: unix, gnu, autoconf, hp-ux, m4

I want to install `autoconf` in a HP-UX server, I downloaded `autoconf-2.58` and ran `configure` and got the following:
[image]

So I downloaded `m4-1.4` and tried to install it. `configure` is okay, but running `make` I got:
[image]

So `m4-1.4` requires `autoconf` be installed ? But `autoconf` needs `m4-1.4` at the same time.

What should I do ?

Comment: `m4-1.4` and `autoconf-2.58`?  Find me a time machine!  Why are you trying to use such old software?

Comment: You might have a clock problem on the build machine or a broken tar version.  Try GNU tar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your screen shot, shows m4 has been installed (found at /bin/m4), but didn't support `frozen files`.

But from http://sunfreeware.saix.net/indexsparc10.html (for Solaris), i didn't see the dependencies list in autoconf which need m4. Normally it should be same in HP_UX.

```
autoconf-2.68-sol10-sparc-local.gz GNU autoconf is a package for generating configure scripts - installs in /usr/local.

m4-1.4.16-sol10-sparc-local.gz GNU `m4' is an implementation of the traditional Unix macro processor - installs in /usr/local. Dependencies: libsigsegv and to obtain libgcc_so.so.1, you will need to install either libgcc-3.4.6 or gcc-3.4.6 or later.
```

First, What you can check is, if `gcc` or `libgcc` has been installed and set properly or not.

Second, check if m4 is in the PATH, such as /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin or not. if it is find in /bin/m4, can you show the version `/bin/m4 --version`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `configure` step actually failed to configure M4.  The `No suffix list.` message is what makes me suspect that.  I downloaded GNU M4 1.4 (dated Nov 1994) `configure`d on linux.  The only make target that I saw that needed `autoconf` was the `configure` target.

You might have better success with a more recent GNU M4/autoconf releases.